# Return onWrite Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating an action in the cloud functions, to return a value when there is a change in the code. But it's making a mistake. what did I do wrong?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.alertHelp = functions.firestore
    .document('chamados/{userId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        const snapshot = change.after;
        const val = snapshot.val();
        const name = val.tid;
        
        console.log(name);
    });
```

```
TypeError: snapshot.val is not a function
    at exports.alertHelp.functions.firestore.document.onWrite (/workspace/index.js:8:30)
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:134:23)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:198:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing a Firestore trigger, which means you are using Firestore APIs to describe the document being written.  `snapshot` is a [DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html) type object.  It has a method called [data()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/DocumentSnapshot.html#data) to get the document data.  There is no method `val()`.  `val()` is what you find in Realtime Database snapshots, which is a completely different database and API.